# Essential singularity question, showing $f(z)$ can not have an essential singularity at certain point.

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Good time of time! I am preparing for an exam and got stuck with one of the problems.

Show that if $f$ is holomorphic in a punctured neighborhood of $z = a$, and satisﬁes in this neighborhood
$|f(z)| ≤ M|z − a|^{−n}$
for some $M > 0$ and $n > 0$, then $z = a$ is not an essential singularity of $f$.

First I have attempted to look at $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$ to show that $z=a$ is actually a removable singularity, but I couldn't bound it (to use Riemann's theorem). Then I've tried to use contradiction-- assume it is an essential singularity and get a contradiction from the fact that $f(0<|z − a|<\epsilon)$ is dense, but got stuck again...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides Casorati or Picard, you can also argue as follows: The function $g(z)=f(z)(z-a)^n$ is holomorphic in a punctured neighborhood of $z=a$ and satisfies $|g(z)|\leq M$ there. Hence, $g$ can be extended holomorphically to $z=a$ (Riemann's Theorem). But then $f(z)=g(z)/(z-a)^n$ has a pole of order at most $n$ at $z=a$.

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice way to do this problem. Never crossed my mind.

Answer (score 1):

By Picard's great theorem, a holomorphic function $f$ on any punctured neighberhood of an essential singularity takes on all possible values in $\mathbb{C}$ except maybe one. However, this function is bounded on an open punctured disk of radius $r>0$:
$$|f(z)|\leq M|z-a|^{-n}\leq \frac{M}{r^n}$$

Comment: I am not allowed to use Picard's theorem on the exam.... is there a way to prove this without Picard's theorem? And your $r$ actually varies.. since $0<|z−a|<ϵ$ you can get as close to zero as you want..

Comment: But no matter how small you make your neighborhood, the function $f$ will still be bounded by $\frac{M}{r^n}$.

Comment: Have you learned the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem for your exam?

Comment: Yes I can use Casoratti.

Comment: Also since it is bounded, can I claim that it is a removable singularity by Riemann's theorem? But if this is the case problem seems too trivial...

Comment: Then we can use a similar argument by saying that $z=a$ is not an essential singularity because otherwise, by the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem, there would be a sequence $z_n$ which converges to $a$ such that $f(z_n)\to \frac{M}{r^n}+1$, which is not possible as shown above.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it, I was put off by the fact that I can vary my $r$. I was trying to use the definition of Casorati without sequences and was not able to bound the random number I've chosen. But your argument with sequences is neat.